# Google Speech API Example, can not resolve R

Tags: android, r, api, gradle, speech

I have imported an Google Speech API example from Google.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech

- It is unable to resolve R.layout
- I have cleaned & rebuilt the project
- Attempted to change the gradle 4.1 to gradle 2.9. Which it did not
  allow me because the minimum gradle required is gradle 4.1

The xml files are from Google, so I assumed they were okay. Still checked them anyway

I also inserted the credential.json inside the project. This is taken from the Google Cloud Platform, if anyone is thinking of using this example. This is very important

The catlog is also giving me this error :

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:extractIncludeDebugProto'.
> Resolving configuration 'debugCompile' directly is not allowed
```

Did anyone have this issue when the trying out this sample code?

Any input is greatly appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, really stupid really.

Just redownloaded the sample , imported it into Android studio.

changed the gradle 3.0 from the initial stage instead of after

hope this helps :)